# SQL Server Management Studio Table Designer won't let me save Not NUll Column

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key-relationship, alter-table, ssms

I am trying to add a foreign relationship between two tables. When I add the FK column to my table and leave the check box for Allow Nulls blank, it wont let me save. Explaining the column does not allow nulls. How to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The Table had data in it.

```
Delete from MyTable
```

Then I was allowed Not Null. Table Saved.